# MUI: navigate to page instance

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

In a Modern UI for Wpf (MUI) application, I would like to navigate to a specific instance of an existing page, e.g.:

```
Page myPageInstance = new Page();
NavigateTo(myPageInstance);
```

but all available methods, like:

```
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/Pages/Page.xaml", this);
```

or:

```
NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
nav.Navigate(myPageInstance)
```

or:

```
NavigationWindow nav = FindAncestor<NavigationWindow>(this);
```

...

```
    public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        if (parent == null) return null;

        var parentT = parent as T;
        return parentT ?? FindAncestor<T>(parent);
    }
```

do not work (the earlier creates a new page instance, the second doesn't find any NavigationService (nav is null), the latter doesn't find any NavigationWindow (of course, as the root is a FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls.ModernWindow))

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to navigate to a specific instance of a view? If using MVVM pattern correctly, your data will be stored in ViewModel classes and the view instance should not matter. Let the application manage the lifetime of the view for you.

Comment: Navigation in the WPF works with [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx) element.

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating my implementation of IContentLoader, so that when a Uri is requested, an instance of the viewModel is associated to the view

Comment: How did you solve the problem with getting a NavigationWindow in MUI? I have the same problem!

Comment: As I said, I implemented IConrentLoader (search for it on the net). Though, I was not very happy of the whole framework, so I finally moved to http://mahapps.metro/